# Prevent Duplicate Entry php with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, duplicates

I am trying to prevent duplicate entries with codeigniter, but it doesn't work anymore.

The data still insert to database despite the same name.

This is the controller code

```
   public function add(){
        $title['title']='Add New';
                $data['data']='Insert New Group';
                $data['exist']= 'This Group already exists';
                $this->load->view('add_pbk_g', $data);
    }

    public function save(){
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('namegroup', 'Name', 'trim|required|is_unique[pbk_groups.Name]');
        if($this->form_validation->run()==false){
            $this->add_pbk_g($Name);
        } else{
            $this->db->insert('pbk_groups',array('Name'=> $this->input->post('namegroup')));

            $this->load->model('mpbk_grup');
            if($this->mpbk_grup->check_grup_exist('$Name')){
                $title['title']='Add New';
                $data['data']='Insert New Group';
                $data['exist']= 'This Group already exists';
                $this->load->view('layout/header', $title);
                $this->load->view('add_pbk_g');
                $this->load->view('layout/footer');
            } else{
                $this->mpbk_grup->add;
                redirect('cpbk_grup/index');   
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the Model..

```
    function add($data){
        return $this->db->create('pbk_groups', $data);
    }

    function check_grup_exist($namegroup){
        $this->db->where('Name', $namegroup);
        $this->db->from('pbk_groups');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows() >0){
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return $query->result();
            //return False;
        }
    }
```

and this is the view

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo site_url('cpbk_grup/save');?>">
              <div class="box-body">
                <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nama Group</label>

                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" name="namegroup" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Nama Group">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /.box-body -->
              <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Save</button>
                <a href="<?php echo base_URL(); ?>index.php/cpbk_grup" class="btn btn-info pull-right"> Kembali</a>
              </div>
              <!-- /.box-footer -->
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function save(){
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('namegroup', 'Name', 'trim|required|is_unique[pbk_groups.Name]');
        if($this->form_validation->run()==false){
            $this->add_pbk_g($Name);
        } else{
            $data = array ('Name' => $this->input->post('namegroup'));
            $this->mpbk_grup->check_grup_exist($data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does $Name on this line come from?

```
if($this->mpbk_grup->check_grup_exist('$Name')){
```

Also it should not have quotes around it, should be...

```
if($this->mpbk_grup->check_grup_exist($Name)){
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this inside save function

```
Controller Code:
$data = array('Name' => $this->input->post('namegroup'));
$this->Model_Name->check_grup_exist($data);
```

My Model

```
Model_Name


$this->main_table = 'pbk_groups';
 public function check_grup_exist($data)
{
 $query = $this->db->get_where($this->main_table, array('Name' => $data['Name']));
if ($query->num_rows() == 0) 
{
  $this->db->insert($this->main_table, $data);
  return $this->db->insert_id();
}
else 
{
  return false;
}
```

Checking duplication data before inserting the data. Let me know if any query occurs.

Comment: where i put the controller code? inside function save?

Comment: then, i got 2 different errors. first, when i input with same entry, errors with line $this->add_pbk_g($name). second, when i input different entry, errors with syntax 'get' on model code.

Comment: Put Model Code in Model File and Controller code in controller file and call model inside controller function

Comment: Yes inside save function

Comment: error? what type of error can you pls show that I can help you

Comment: when i input with same entry, the error displays Fatal error: Call to undefined method cpbk_grup::add_pbk_g() in C:\xampp\htdocs\smsgateway3\application\controllers\cpbk_grup.php on line 24
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined method cpbk_grup::add_pbk_g()

Filename: controllers/cpbk_grup.php

Line Number: 24

Backtrace:

Comment: can I see that how you are calling the model of function inside controller?

Comment: when i input with different entry, the error displays:
Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\smsgateway3\application\models\mpbk_grup.php
Line: 11
Function: __get

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\smsgateway3\application\controllers\cpbk_grup.php
Line: 30
Function: check_grup_exist

Comment: i put it on the comment

Comment: Try debugging the function by putting die inside model function and check is it executing or not

Comment: it says "array(1) { ["Name"]=> string(4) "TEST" }"

Comment: that means your data is been passed correctly, now try doing this just after running your query in model,,#echo $this->db->last_query();exit; before returning anything